# My SQL query Difference between two Dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

My DataBaseTable looks as follow

```
> Date                    Value 
> 2020-09-05 00:00:05     20.58 --> first value
> 2020-09-05 00:01:05     20.59 
> ..... 
> 2020-09-05 23:59:05     21.00 --> last value
```

Result should be 21.00 - 20.58 = 0.42

I want for example built a difference over a day.
With this query I get the first and last value, in my c# project I can then calculate the difference

```
WITH T AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM fernleitung
   WHERE `Date` between '2020.09.05-00:00:00' AND '2020.09.06-00:00:00'
   )
   (SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Is there an easier way to do this with an SQL query?

Many Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Tag your database please!!

Comment: `built a difference ofer` Eh?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation

```
select max(value)-min(value)
from tablename where `Date` between '2020.09.05-00:00:00' AND '2020.09.06-00:00:00'
group by date(datecol)
```

Comment: in my case the values only can increse, so i can use aggegation, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Fahmi will return the value difference between the last event and the first event, but for all dates. So if you have 1 year of data you will have 365 rows and you have to find the right date in them.

This can work in some cases, but for your actual case, you should just do the following and it will return the computation only for that date (thus one row)

```
SELECT (MAX(value) - MIN(value) ) AS the_difference
FROM tablename
WHERE `Date` between '2020.09.05-00:00:00' AND '2020.09.06-00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean in this case value can be not only increased, but also decreased trough one day. So you can not use MIN or MAX functions in this case.
Since MySQL 8.0 window functions introduced they can be used as well:

```
select distinct
    date(date),
    last_value(value) over (partition by date(date)) -
    first_value(value) over (partition by date(date)) as day_diff
from fernleitung;
```

Here yiu can look [live SQL fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7149af6f93b02fdebc775990209cd686&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

The older MySQL version need more complex code, but also can be solved.